# How do i increment a formula by a number greater than 1?

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have a workbook that is used for time tracking. It has one sheet that has time cards and then a summary sheet. What i would like to to is take the information from the time cards and use formulas to move it to the summary sheet. The problem is that Each time card is 14 rows high. So when I drag the first formula down if the cell is a2 that I am getting the name from I get A3 as the next formula but I need it to be A16. It needs to add 14 every time. I know I could do this with a macro but I figure there should be away without one. Is there anyway to do that with the auto complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use (eg)

```
=OFFSET(TimeCards!$A$1,(ROW()-2)*14,0)
```

If your timecard headers start on row 1 and the formulas on the summary sheet start on row2.

Adjust to suit your exact layout.